# How to run an Event (FileSystemWatcher) through Task Scheduler

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, filesystemwatcher, windows-server-2012-r2, powershell-4.0

I currently have a pretty simple Powershell Script that creates an **IO.FileSystemWatcher** object, and calls an executable upon that event being triggered.

I can run this script without issue from Administrator Powershell on my 2012 Windows Server, however it seems to run into issues when I have my script being run from **Task Scheduler**.

I've attempted running the task while logged on, and on a trigger while I'm logged off and in both instances the Event status reads: "Running" when I check. However interacting with the folder that should be watched produces no results. I've added a log file to document which parts of the code are functioning and the script DOES create the event, however it is the event triggering that seems to be the issue. Has anyone heard of an issue with creating events through Task Scheduler?

I've read some forums that say it might be a domain user issue

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
>
> Change the ‘REG_DWORD’ with ValueName ‘disabledomaincreds’ to a Value to “0

Although this was already the case, and I've tried multiple variations of settings in the Task Properties as per [Scripting Guy](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2011/01/12/schedule-powershell-scripts-that-require-input-values/) and [SpiceWorks](https://community.spiceworks.com/how_to/17736-run-powershell-scripts-from-task-scheduler). The general consensus I've found is that it needs to be ran with a -NoExit argument in order for the event to properly run when the user is not logged in.

### Extra notes:

- Powershell script is located on a network location rather than physically on the computer (\serverName\FTP\Folder\script.ps1

Comment: If you told us what those issues are, we might be able to help. As presented, your question belongs on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Comment: Sorry, new to the community. Hopefully my edit clarifies!

Comment: You should just look at [File Server Resource Manager](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732431(v=ws.11).aspx)

Comment: `-NoExit` is required regardless of whether the user is logged in or not - the event registration only persists in that session, so if the process exits, the FileSystemWatcher dies as well

Comment: I'll look into the File Server Resource Manager, thanks for the suggestion - if that's able to run an executable with params upon File Creation, that could be a viable alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem. I don't know why this works, but in your Scheduled Task, when referring to the PowerShell Script, instead of using

```
\serverName\FTP\Folder\script.ps1
```

use

```
. \serverName\FTP\Folder\script.ps1
```

(noting the `.`).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, as a powershell novice, the events you register with FileSystemWatcher will only fire if the powershell instance is still running.  I wouldn't trust that task manager says the task is running since it is notoriously unreliable, which seems to be the Microsoft standard.  I think once your script finishes executing it kills the powershell instance and all event listeners are garbage collected.

I just put my script to sleep forever and it works. At the end of my script, it has

while ($true) {sleep 1}

It probably wouldn't hurt to increase the sleep time, but this works.